# Conversion from string in Erlang

Tags: erlang, redis

I used **Redis database** for storing my data in **Erlang** through **eredis client**. And one of my output is `<<"{{1391,764334,959623},<0.437.0>}">>` And now I need to convert the above output to  `[{{1391,764334,959623},<0.437.0>}]`. But I can't get it. I followed some code as,

```
String = "[1,2,3].",
{ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(String),
{ok, Term} = erl_parse:parse_term(Ts),
```

And

```
D = binary_to_list(Data),
{ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string(D ++ "."),
{ok, Term} = erl_parse:parse_term(Tokens),
```

The above code is working perfect for other string. But I didn't get the expected output for this string format `"{{1391,764334,959623},<0.437.0>}"`

Comment: do you *control* the data you store? If so, may I suggest using `term_to_binary` and `binary_to_term` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using various `binary` functions:

```
B = <<"{{1391,764334,959623},<0.437.0>}">>.
F = binary:replace(B,[<<"{">>, <<"}">>], <<"">>, [global]). % Flatten the structure
[T1,T2,T3,PidBin] = binary:split(F, <<",">>, [global]).
Result = [{{binary_to_integer(T1),
            binary_to_integer(T2),
            binary_to_integer(T3)},
            list_to_pid(binary_to_list(PidBin))}].
```

A potential problem with this is if you have stored external pids in the string format, `list_to_pid` will throw an exception if you try to convert a string like "<1.232.0>" (external pid) to a process identifier.

Answer (score 2):

When you see bracketed things like `<0.437.0>` in the shell or error reports, it is only a representation to some data (Pids, Sockets, Ports, Funs, …).

Erlang does not even *lexe/scan* this angular-bracketed stuff. You'll need to treat your data before passing it to **erl_parse**.

What you could do is make such things strings: `<0.437.0>` → `"<0.437.0>"`

Comment: thanks for your response johlo answer is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [re](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#split-2).

```
 B= <<"{{1391,764334,959623},<0.437.0>}">>.
 L = binary:bin_to_list(B).
 [_, _, T1, T2, T3, _, PidStr, _] = re:split(L, "[{,}]", [{return, list}]).
 Res = [{{list_to_integer(T1), list_to_integer(T2), list_to_integer(T3)}, list_to_pid(PidStr)}].
```